# Need to implement watch dog like functionlity to server update. ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, observable, ionic3

Currently I am using below code to check any server update that check server in every 5 sec if any update from server it show notification and popup. But I don't want to user timer instead i want something like new SMS or Call comes. similarly any update on server the popup will come without taking much time like someone is observing.

```
setInterval(function(){ 
   this.dbProcess.dataProcess('','getServerUpdate.php').subscribe(
   data => { 
    //console.log("getRequests", data);
    this.response = data;
    this.response = this.response._body;
    this.response = JSON.parse(this.response);
    console.log(this.response.REQUEST)
    console.log("Timer Running : " + localStorage.getItem('timer'))
    if(this.response.RESPONSE == "success"){ 
      console.log("success"); 
      this.timer = localStorage.getItem('timer');
      clearInterval(this.timer);
      localStorage.setItem('timer', "end");
      console.log("Timer Ended" + this.timer);          
      this.vibration.vibrate(1000);          
      this.localNotifications.schedule( {
        id: this.response.REQUEST.RequestId,
        title: 'New Ride Request (' + this.response.REQUEST.firstname + ' ' +this.response.REQUEST.lastname + ')' ,
        text: this.response.REQUEST.FromLocation + ' ' +this.response.REQUEST.ToLocation + ' ' + this.response.REQUEST.EstimatedCost,
      } 
);

      this.modal = this.modalCtrl.create(JobRequestPage);           
      this.modal.present();
    }
    else{
      console.log("Failure");
    }
  }, 
    err => { //on error this will execute
      console.log("server error");
      //this.showError(err);
    },
    () =>{ // on complete this will execute
      console.log("completed");
    }    
);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for push notifications.

You should implement push via Firebase, Onesignal, Amazon or others in your Ionic app. Then in your backend you call an API of your chosen push provider that sends a push notification to your user's device (you can send to all or individual users that are affected by the changing data - you can decide that in your backend). You can handle that notification in any way you want in your app, including presenting a modal or similar.

Comment: Is the Observable thing are different than push notification?

Comment: Yes, Observable are something different, more for the flow of logic in your code. You have a problem of outside information being handled here, that is much better handled on the server side.